# How to check a table whether a set of data is present

Tags: sql-server

I want to check if a set of strings is present in a particular column in a table.
Say like

```
'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', ...
```

i want to know what are the strings present and string which not present.

Comment: Since you had "MSSQL" in the title, I've removed the [mysql] tag.

Comment: Do you want to find if all of those strings are present, or any of them? What do you expect back if there is a row with `'ABC'` but none with `'DEF'` or `'GHI'`? What if there are two rows with `'ABC'`? Do you want a count or the data? Do you want it to be an exact match or a partial? To help people help you better, it's usually good to include some sample data and results you expect from the query. It also helps if you can decide whether you're using MySQL or SQL Server, and specify the version.

Comment: Thanks Aaron,I want to find which are the strings present in the column and which are the strings which are not present. I am afraid i cant give any sample data here.

Comment: Sample data like `'ABC'`, `'DEF'`, etc.? That doesn't look too secret to me. I don't mean your actual data but surely you can represent what you're after. Word problems like "(not) present in the column" are not very helpful in describing what you are actually after.

Comment: Where are you getting the set of candidate strings from?  Is it a hard-coded set, or are they in another reference table?

Comment: Also, how many strings are we talking about?  It might actually be easier to just create a reference table and put them in there.

Comment: Is each type in a spearate row or are all the types stored in a comma delimited list?

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE Field IN ('ABC,'DEF', 'ETC')`

Comment: thanks for your response. Sorry i forgot to mention i want to know what are the strings present and string which not present. I will update my question.

Comment: Your description is still not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the candidate strings into a reference table `refTable`, and the data you're searching is in a table called `myTable`, and the column name you're searching is `stringvalue`, then I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT r.stringvalue, COUNT(t.stringvalue) numPresent
FROM refTable r
LEFT JOIN myTable t
    ON t.stringvalue = r.stringvalue
GROUP BY r.stringvalue
```

The key here is using COUNT(t.stringvalue) rather than COUNT(*), since MSSQL's COUNT() only includes non-NULL values, and the LEFT JOIN produces NULLs for all columns in t where there is no match.

Depending on the size of refTable and myTable, this could be slow, so you might also want to add an index on `stringvalue` to both tables.